# PostgreSQL index on a composite type of key + range

Tags: postgresql, indexing, composite, postgresql-9.6, composite-types

Consider this SQL:

```
create type kv AS
(
  key   int4,
  val   int4range
);

create table test
(
  id serial primary key,
  data kv[] not null
);

insert into test (data)
values (array[(1, '[10,20]'),(2, '[30,40]')]::kv[])
```

I want to be able to query (in pseudo-code) "give me all IDs where the key is `1` and its value overlaps `5 to 15` and the key is `2` and its value overlaps `38 to 60`, etc.

Is this possible?

I added the following to allow the value to be indexed, but it's not correct because it omits the key:

```
CREATE OPERATOR CLASS gin_int4range_ops
    DEFAULT FOR TYPE int4range[] USING gin AS
        OPERATOR        1       =(anyrange,anyrange),
        FUNCTION        1       lower(anyrange),
        FUNCTION        2       upper(anyrange),
        FUNCTION        3       isempty(anyrange),
        FUNCTION        4       lower_inc(anyrange),
        FUNCTION        5       upper_inc(anyrange);

create index ix_test on test using gin (data->val gin_int4range_ops); << error & needs to include the key
```

Comment: Note: Naming a column the same as its type is *at least* confusing.

Comment: Fair enough. I edited it,

Comment: I get the feeling that your`key` is in fact a natural/candidate key (duh!) and it thus should not be hidden inside a UDT-blob. it violates 1NF (and 2NF)

Comment: This is obviously trivial to do in standard form. I'm trying to take advantage of PG's arrays and exotic indexes. Normalization is trivial to achieve via a function and trigger.